# tikz: show 0 at the axis origin

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I show the "0" value at the axis origin?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid style=dashed,grid=both,ymin=0,ymax=70,xmax=0.35,xmin=0,
               minor tick num=1,axis lines = middle,xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=T\;$(\si{\celsius})$,
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.1,0.03)},anchor=north},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:0,1.0)},anchor=south},     x tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    fixed relative,
                },          
               ]
  \addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0.05,31.9)(0.10,30.1)(0.20,35.8)(0.31,65.4)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Phase diagram of a partially miscible binary liquid system]
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}       % <--- i suggest you to upgrade pgfplots

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  ymin=0,ymax=70,
  extra y ticks={0},            % <---
  xmax=0.35,xmin=0,
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  minor tick num=1,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  axis on top,                  % <---
  xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=T\;$(\si{\celsius})$,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed relative,
                     },
               ]
  \addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0.05,31.9)(0.10,30.1)(0.20,35.8)(0.31,65.4)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been trying for half an hour but I couldn't find the solution :-( +1

Comment: to be honest, i do not understand why is necessary this trick with extra ticks. thank you very much!

Comment: My sincere congratulation to the kindest OP called: Zarko.